Reading .xlsx results in a ValueError: Unable to read workbook. This is most probably because the workbook source files contain some invalid XML
I'm trying to read and clean an Excel workbook that contains an image. My goal is to process it automatically, as I have many similar files. I used the following code to read the file:
df = pd.read_excel('/content/MYFILE.xlsx')

However, I encountered the following error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

ValueError: Unable to read workbook: could not read stylesheet from /content/MYFILE.xlsx.
This is most probably because the workbook source files contain some invalid XML.
Please see the exception for more details.

When I removed the image, the processing worked perfectly. Can anyone suggest a way to read a workbook while ignoring the broken stylesheet?

pandas cannot read imagen, you have somehow exclude them

Please add a sample xlsx file to try out the error and have reproducible sample of error. Also add detailed error log.

@DavidDale BTW I'd try to unzip the xlsx-file, remove xl/styles.xml, and zip them back as xlsx (additional tweaks may be needed in [Content_Types].xml). This might be excessive if the problem can be repaired by Excel and most styles can be preserved. But at least this approach can be done programmatically to allow further reading of the data while ignoring the styles.

you should use another library because pandas can't "read" images from your excel file.
try using "from openpyxl import load_workbook"
Load workbook ignoring styles
wb = load_workbook('/content/MYFILE.xlsx', data_only=True)
